# Connect Raspberry Pi to access controller Z-5R by GPIO

Tags: gpio

I try to understand how to control Z-5R. Z-5R - it's access controller, that control the electromagnetic lock by RFID cards. I want to control this device by Raspberry Pi. How I can plug it correct? 
I want use a GPIO contacts + EXIT contact on Z-5R.
If you need an additional info, please comment.

[image: Z-5R controller]

Z-5R info - https://ironlogic.me/en/access-control/access-control-equipment/acs-controllers/z-5r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a relay module for 3,3 volt. connect the relay contacts in parallel with the EXIT button. And the control signal for the relay module you connect it to a GPIO on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank you. Addition question: what difference between using 3,3/5V relay? Raspberry Pi has a 5V power pin too.

Comment: The GPIO pin can deliver a voltage between  0 - 3,3 volt. The 5V powerpin is the power from the USB port, after that there is a voltage regulator that adjust the voltage to 3,3 volt that is used internally in the Raspberry Pi.